# Why would this take so long to compute?

Tags: r, performance, execution

I am trying to redefine a variable value based on a condition, i.e., see the code here:

```
Data1 = data.frame(ifelse(Cohort <= 201806, "Pilot", 0))
```

For some reason, it is taking forever to execute in R and I am not sure why.

Any thoughts?  (Brand new to R but I would expect it to be able to handle something like this very easily).

```
Data1 = data.frame(ifelse(Cohort <= 201806, "Pilot", 0))
```

Comment: about 100,000 observations, so not terribly large data set

Comment: Hi, how much time does it takes?

Comment: Try `c("0", "Pilot")[(Cohort<=201806) + 1]`

Comment: `ifelse` is slow. Adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to `data.frame(` should give a speed up.

Comment: akrun is right, altough even with your code BuJay it takes my pc under 4 sec to run it (with a data of similar size).

Comment: thanks - I'd actually like to retain the cohort variable value if the Cohort <= 201806, so I like the suggestion by akrun - thanks!

Ultimately, I need something like this:

If Cohort <= 201806, then replace Cohort with string "Pilot" otherwise, retain the Cohort value

Comment: it's so hard to struggle with R when I could have had this done 10 years ago in excel! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I just tried to post a solution but not sure if it posted (since new to StackOverflow)

I think this works:

```
Cohort$Cohort[Cohort$Cohort<="201806"] = "Pilot"
```